# using dataset to classifying and labelling another unlabeded dataset

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, transfer-learning, semi-supervised-learning

I collect a collection of posts from Facebook and I use a published sentiment datset to labeling my collected dataset.
is this a right technique and what its name is this transfer-learning ?

Comment: depends on the similarity of the pre-trained with the one you are using as well.

Comment: how to calculate similarity ??

Comment: @ Aditya     how I can do this?